# Check if fields in a column are dates and convert them

Tags: sql, actian

I am creating a process that will eventually get data from one place and place it into another. For this to happen, I need to transform my data.

I have a column that contains string's and dates

```
timestamp
20POST /xxxei/adsa/ContentVis HTTP/1.1  Host: fa.aweb.com
2016-12-18T00:15:10.289Z
2016-11-06T04:09:54.503Z
```

I was doing this:

```
select cast(left("timestamp",10) as timestamp)
```

but now my process is failing because I didn't account for this, as a value:

```
20POST /xxxei/adsa/ContentVis HTTP/1.1  Host: fa.aweb.com
```

My system doesn't take the function ISDATE(), do you guys have any ideas this cinco de Mayo.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Does it support regular expressions?

Comment: yes, it does support regular expressions. I am using Actian Analytics Database

Answer (score 0):

You can use a funciton like DAY() on that string. if it returns null, it's not a valid date

More specific to your case:

```
SELECT DAY('20POST /xxxei/adsa/ContentVis HTTP/1.1  Host: fa.aweb.com') IS NOT NULL as is_date;

SELECT DAY('2016-12-18T00:15:10.289Z') IS NOT NULL as is_date;
```